# Crystal Report print functionlity doesn't work after deployment?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, deployment, crystal-reports

I'm using crystal reports to build reports, everything is ok while development.
But after deployment of website, print functionality doesn't work.

I use _rptDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0); to print report.

I've tried two methods to deploy website

1. Normal Publish option.
2. Web Deployment Project.

But I got the same output, print functionality doesn't work.
Also, I tried to set default printer, this also doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing on a web server isn`t a good idea. What should happen? A user prints on your servers printer? Use CR to create PDFs. Stream them to your clients. They can use their local printers.

Comment: CR should printed on local PCs of client.

Comment: Ok - That's excatly the scenario where I use PDF creation instead of printing. Your code is server-side (ASP.NET). There is no knowledge about the clients printing environment on the server.

Comment: +1, PDF generation is exactly what I would use in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

try this :- Create PDF and open Browser Tab ...`enter code here`

```
string fname = "Report" + ".pdf";`enter code here`
        //Create instance for crystal report Export option class
        ExportOptions exprtopt = default(ExportOptions);

        //create instance for destination option - This one is used to set path of your pdf file save 
        DiskFileDestinationOptions destiopt = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();

        //Bind data in the crystal report first before export cystal report to PDF
        ReportDocument RptDoc = new ReportDocument();

        //Map your crystal report path
        //  RD.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport2.rpt"));

        //Set your crystal report datasource as dt


        //Get path and assign into destination DiskFileName
        destiopt.DiskFileName = Server.MapPath(fname);

        exprtopt = RD.ExportOptions;
        exprtopt.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;

        //use PortableDocFormat for PDF data
        exprtopt.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
        exprtopt.DestinationOptions = destiopt;

        //finally export your report document
        RD.Export();

        //To open your PDF after save it from crystal report

        string Path = Server.MapPath(fname);

        //create instance to client to open your pdf
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        //Assign path to download pdf
        Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(Path);

        //metion content type as PDF and write
        // Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        //Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
        //Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);

        //======================================
        Response.Write("<script>");
        Response.Write("window.open('" + fname + "', '_newtab');");
        Response.Write("</script>");
        //===================================
```

IMTIYAZ